# Provide TrAX parser example in Java (XML to XML) XSLT Transformation

Tags: java, xml

I need to write code in Jave using TrAX for transform one XML to another XML.

First XML contain information about employees (Name, Salary). The second XML should contain only those employees who has salary more than X, X given from keyboard.

Can you help me with this task or provide me some example in Java?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=TraX+java+example&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uyKDU4ulCIbR8ge6zIDICg

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xslt+example+in+java & click the first link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**data.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <employees-list>    <employee>
            <name>Christopher Abani</name>
            <salary>3000</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <name>Sait Faik Abasıyanık</name>
            <salary>10000</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <name>Christina Abbey</name>
            <salary>2100</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <name>Edward Abbey</name>
            <salary>2300</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <name>Lynn Abbey</name>
            <salary>2000</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <name>Edwin A. Abbott</name>
            <salary>1000</salary>
        </employee>
    </employees-list>
```

**input.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>

<!-- Receives the id of the menu being rendered. -->
<xsl:param name="MinSalary" />

    <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <HTML> 
    <body>    
        <xsl:for-each select="employees-list/employee[salary>$MinSalary]">
            <employee>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>                      
                <salary><xsl:value-of select="salary"/></salary>
            </employee>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body> 
    </HTML>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**trans.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class trans {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xsl = new StreamSource("input.xsl");
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);
        Source xml = new StreamSource("data.xml");
        Result result = new StreamResult("out.xml");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Input min salary:");
        String minSalary = reader.readLine();
        transformer.setParameter("MinSalary", minSalary);
        transformer.transform(xml, result);


    }
}
```

**out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><HTML>
<body>
<employee>
<name>Christopher Abani</name>
<salary>3000</salary>
</employee>
<employee>
<name>Sait Faik Abasıyanık</name>
<salary>10000</salary>
</employee>
<employee>
<name>Christina Abbey</name>
<salary>2100</salary>
</employee>
<employee>
<name>Edward Abbey</name>
<salary>2300</salary>
</employee>
</body>
</HTML>
```